# Two conjectural infinite series for $\pi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, elementary-proofs

I am looking for a proofs of the following two claims:

> **Claim 1.**
> $$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\Omega_1(n)}}{n}$$ where $\Omega_1(n)$ is the number of prime factors of the form $p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}$ of $n$ .

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9TcsKwjAQvOc_hN0abVPBS9hv0LtUaCWpS23UvC6i32566VyGeTCTBlLNAi1Osxl7BQ7pw9ToTLa_xacvhraFJlLyYdwY75B_KNlCvkxSdZsjlYSJt4tuO0TtTUzeAaP-ikAhzeBKJQ0SYKfwuh5hXbbFy7OLECq1X0VbnbkObx_hUOb-A88xLQ==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

> **Claim 2.**
> $$\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{\Omega_5(n)}}{n}$$ where $\Omega_5(n)$ is the number of prime factors of the form $p \equiv 5 \pmod{6}$ of $n$ .

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjc0KwjAQhO99D2G3RttU6iXsM-hdKrSS1KU2av4uos9uetG5DN_AzMSBZL1IFYdZj30LFunFVKtEpr-Eu8uBMtkmkuKm7RiukD4o2EA6TUJ2qz1RK5h4vXDTISqnQ3QWGNW78OTjDDaX4yAANhLPvyOs8nbxcGwD-FJu__B0AXZYHrlqUH0BCzcxOQ==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: you count prime divisors with multiplicity, right?

Comment: The first one doesn't seem to be particularly close from the SageMath cell linked.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Right.

Comment: @gmvh Perhaps it converges very slowly.

Comment: So is there another reason besides the numerical coincidence to believe this conjecture?

Comment: @gmvh There is a similar series for $\pi$ in the literature given by Euler.

Comment: Perhaps one could take advantage of the fact that the product of the LHS equals $\pi^2$.

Comment: I think Ramanujan produced a formula along these lines, for expressions the product of which equals $\pi^2$.

Comment: @PeđaTerzić Which formula of Euler's did you have in mind (if a specific one)?

Comment: Isn't the second series just $3\cdot L(1,\chi)$, where $\chi$ is the non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $6$? And the product of the two series is $9\cdot \prod_{p\ge 5}(1-p^{-2})^{-1}=6\zeta(2)=\pi^2$?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Other_infinite_series

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You recently asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246647/a-conjectural-infinite-series-for-frac-pi2) for modulus $4$ on math.stackexchange. I just used the exact same technique.

---

For $i\in\{1,5\}$, define $f_i:\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ by $f_i(n)=(-1)^{\Omega_i(n)}$, then $f_i$ is completely multiplicative and
$$L(s,f_i)=\left(1-2^{-s}\right)^{-1}\left(1-3^{-s}\right)^{-1}\prod_{p\equiv i\pmod 6}\left(1+p^{-s}\right)^{-1}\prod_{p\equiv -i\pmod 6}\left(1-p^{-s}\right)^{-1}.$$
Hence,
$$L(s,f_1)L(s,f_5)=\left(1-2^{-s}\right)^{-2}\left(1-3^{-s}\right)^{-2}\prod_{p\ge 5}\left(1-p^{-2s}\right)^{-1}=\frac{2^{s}+1}{2^s-1}\cdot\frac{3^s+1}{3^s-1}\cdot \zeta(2s).$$
Therefore, if both $L(1,f_1)$ and $L(1,f_5)$ converge, their product is $6\zeta(2)=\pi^2$. Now, let $\chi$ be the non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $6$, then
$$L(1,\chi)=\prod_{ p\equiv 1\pmod 5}(1-p^{-1})^{-1}\prod_{p\equiv 5\pmod{6}}\left(1+p^{-1}\right)^{-1}=\frac13L(1,f_5).$$
Therefore, it suffices to show that $L(1,\chi)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}.$

Let $\chi_2$ be the non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $3$, then $\chi(p)=\chi_2(p)$ for all primes $p\neq 2$ and
$$L(1,\chi)=\frac{L(1,\chi_2)}{(1+2^{-1})^{-1}}=\frac32 \cdot \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt 3}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$$
Where we use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906424/analogue-of-zeta2-frac-pi26-for-dirichlet-l-series-of-mathbbz-3/906443#906443) answer.